# Is there a simple way to show an image with a color depth of 10 bits on screen using Python?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, configuration, hdr

I have a use case where I get images from Carla simulator buffer in a python script, running on a Win10 localhost, and I want to show these images on an HDR screen in a full 10 bit color depth.

Unfortunately I have not found a library yet that is capable of showing 10bit images and I wouldn't have expected this to be so complicated. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Best regards
Robert

Comment: Are they video or still images? What device do they come from? How does the manufacturer suggest displaying them? What OS do you use?

Comment: It's not a movie but single images. I use Win10 and I create these images using the Carla simulator.

Comment: Requests for tools and libraries are off-topic, and for helping you with your code, you need to include the code (as a [mcve]) in the question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is such a way - be it using your current GPU + O/S + HDMI + Monitor available capabilities ( Intel [advises](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000057279/graphics/graphics-for-8th-generation-intel-processors.html) how do a setup for theirs graphics chips, similarly do other HW manufacturers ),

> <sub>**Summary**</sub>
>
> Integrated Graphics can support 10-bit color depth.
>
> **Description**
>
> How to find out if your Intel® Graphics device supports a display with 10-bit color depth.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> Intel Graphics supports 10-bit and 12-bit color depths (known as deep color). The current Intel Grapchics Driver sets the color depth per the OS configuration by default. **You can also manually set the color depth to 10 or 12 bit** starting with Intel® Graphics Command Center version 1.100.3407.0 for native HDMI connections (if supported by the display).
>
> You can also enable HDR (High Dynamic Range) and WCG (Wide Color Gamut) in the operating systems for higher color depths by going to ***Windows > Display settings > Windows HD Color***. If the content you're trying to view is 10-bit, switch to Full Screen mode, and the driver will automatically switch to the higher color depth, given HDR and WCC are enabled. This is also true for most DirectX applications.
>
> **Note**
> The operating system, application being viewed, and driver will automatically determine which is the best mode to display dynamically.

or
using some other, HDR-Deep-Color [ready hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data#Structure,_version_1.4) chain, as defined since about 2006 ( RPi possibly being one example of the simplest and cheapest case of doing such move )

[image]